# Merging Projects

Tags: xcode, merge, cocos2d-iphone, projects

I want to create books for the iPad.
I also want to be to write an app that will give access to those books
and allow me to add more books, without having to re-download the entire app.

My idea is to have a Main project that shows all the available books.
then a separate project for each book which will be downloaded individually (like a sub-project).

Is this possible?
If so, how will I be able to merge the main project with the "sub-project"?

if not, how will I be able to achieve this?

I saw something similar on an app called "Interactive Touch Books for Kids"

I'm using xcode 4.3 and cocos2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Xcode projects is concerned, these apps will all be separate Xcode projects. The only thing you can (and should) share is common code, for example the cocos2d library. You do that by creating a static library target for the commonly used code.

As for your main app, keep in mind that you can not instruct the App Store to download another app on your behalf. The user experience will have to be that once the user clicks on a book to download it, he is taken to the App Store app where he can download the book.

In case I mis-understood you and you want all of the books in the same app, you need to implement In-App Purchases to either unlock or download additional content. Regardless of how you setup your Xcode project for that app, users will always have to download an update for your app if you add a new book or make modifications to an existing one. Unless you implement content downloads. But that has nothing to do with the project setup in Xcode.

Comment: Awesome! Then content downloads is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Is there a tutorial I can follow to learn how to do this?

Comment: You can find inspiration from my Cocos2D Webcam Viewer: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/02/cocos2d-webcam-viewer-part-2-asynchronous-texture-loading/